# calculating stress invariants using matrix

Tags: matrices

As in the attached picture below, how to find the values of I2 and I3?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3sST.png)

Comment: The attached picture already has the formulas for calculating them right there. What more are you after?

Comment: Hello, @PaulSinclair ,
No, they are the results, 
am deriving them ( my derivation for I1 is correct) but could't derive I2 and I3,

Can you help on this?

thanks,

Comment: Expand the two expressions for $II$ and $III$. Do they match the expression you have as the coefficient of $\lambda$ and the constant term?

Comment: from the upper picture, I want to get an expressions for I2 and I3 that are similar to the lower left picture, I couldn't do that. Can you help me with this dear @PaulSinclair

Comment: And the step you need to take now is to start with the *formulas for $II$ and $III$ in the lower left picture*, expand them out, and see if they match what you have on top.

Comment: I understand your idea @PaulSinclair , but before I expand the formulas for I2 and I3, I should make more simplification to the upper picture, which I don't know where to start...

Comment: No. The very NEXT step you should take is the one I am telling you. Trust me on this. You don't need to play around with the top. You need to look at it from the other direction. Once you see how those expressions look in terms of the individual components, then you will be able to compare them to your calculations.

Comment: I am fully trusting you dear @PaulSinclair , but what if the lower left picture wasn’t there? Anyway, can you help with their expansion? I will be very thankful

Comment: Then you wouldn't know what form you were aiming for, and what you've already done would be the answer. If you do what I'm telling you to do, it will show you how to get from where you are to where you want to go. You should at very least be able to recognize your expession for the constant term as the determinant of $T$.

Comment: Thanks for all your time dear @PaulSinclair , can you help me with the expansion of I2 and I3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your text $$I = T_{11} + T_{22}+T_{33}\\II =\frac{T_{ij}T_{ij} - I^2}2\\III=\det \mathbf T$$

You've proven the first formula. The last formula is almost trivial to prove without expanding it in elements. After all, $III$ is the constant term of the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda) = \det(\mathbf T - \lambda\mathbf E)$, where $\mathbf E$ is the identity matrix. The constant term of $p$ is the value of $p(\lambda)$ when $\lambda = 0$.
Therefore $$III = p(0) = \det(\mathbf T - 0\cdot \mathbf E) = \det \mathbf T$$

That leaves only $II$. $$\begin{align}I^2 &= (T_{11} + T_{22} + T_{33})^2\\&=T_{11}^2 + T_{22}^2 + T_{33}^2+2(T_{11}T_{22} + T_{11}T_{33} + T_{22}T_{33})\end{align}$$

I had assumed without bothering to check that $T_{ij}T_{ij}$ was making use of the Einstein summation convention. But that isn't true. Your calculation of $II$ is correct:
$$II = T_{12}T_{21} + T_{13}T_{31} + T_{23}T_{32} - T_{11}T_{22} - T_{11}T_{33} - T_{22}T_{33}$$
But if we interpret this per the convention
$$T_{ij}T_{ij} = \sum_{i, j} T_{ij}^2 = T_{11}^2 + T_{22}^2 +T_{33}^2 +T_{12}^2 +T_{21}^2 +T_{13}^2 +T_{31}^2 +T_{23}^2 +T_{32}^2$$ the expression clearly does not give the correct result.

It is actually well-known that for 3x3 matrices, $II = \frac{\operatorname{tr}(T^2) - (\operatorname{tr}(T))^2}2 = \frac{\operatorname{tr}(T^2) - I^2}2$. So apparently $T_{ij}T_{ij}$ is supposed to be $\operatorname{tr}(T^2)$, but I see no way that this makes sense as a notational shorthand.

So instead, let me use the notation which does make sense (though is not a particularly good way to *calculate* the coefficient, since it involves a lot of wasted calculation):

$$\mathbf T^2 = \begin{bmatrix}T_{11}^2 + T_{12}T_{21} + T_{13}T_{31} & ... & ...\\ ... & T_{21}T_{12} + T_{22}^2 + T_{23}T_{32} & ...\\...&...&T_{31}T_{13} + T_{32}T_{23} + T_{33}^2\end{bmatrix}$$
where I haven't bothered to expand the entries that will not contribute to the trace. So, $$\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf T^2) = T_{11}^2 + T_{22}^2 +T_{33}^2 + 2(T_{12}T_{21} + T_{13}T_{31} + T_{31}T_{13})$$

It is should be easy now to get from $\frac{\operatorname{tr}(T^2) - I^2}2$ to your coefficient for $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks indeed @Paul Sinclair for your helpful answer,
I will look into your answer deeply and will let you know if I have more questions.

Sincerely,